# How do I get the fiscal year to start on a specific date each year in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I used the formula listed here to generate a [fiscal year based on the current month](http://web.archive.org/save/www.contextures.com/fiscalyearcalculations.html). I have an odd requirement where she wants the fiscal year to start on 6/20. For example, any dates ranging from 6/20/2014 to 6/19/2014 will Fiscal Year 15.

Can someone help me figure out the formula?

My formula is currently is:

`=IF(MONTH(J2)>=7,YEAR(J2)+1,YEAR(J2))`

Column J has the date that I need to calculate the fiscal year for.

So, I am close where anything from July (7) to December (12) will be calculated as the current year + 1.

Comment: How about posting your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Awww, figured it out. I had to put in a nested `IF` to check if the month = 6 and date is >= 20.

`=IF(AND(MONTH(P2)=6,DAY(P2) >= 20),YEAR(P2)+1,IF(MONTH(P2)>=7,YEAR(P2)+1,YEAR(P2)))`

I don't like to use nested `IF` statements, but it seems like a necessary evil this time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to shorten the formula somewhat with `EDATE` and `EOMONTH`.

[image]

The formula in B2 is,

`=YEAR(EOMONTH(EDATE(A2,6),0)+(DAY(A2)>19))`

Fill down as necessary. I've applied a *custom number format* using *F\Y 0000*. This leaves the year as a true number that can be used in future calculation while visibly displaying the fact that it is an offset fiscal year. From past experience, I do not recommend that you concatenate *FY* as a string as it renders the value useless for calculations.

[EDATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EDATE-function-857e149f-f013-4581-8d35-4f96b376c9ed?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[EOMONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-1525129b-fafb-44fc-90cd-4bea29ddda57?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: This looks good. I'll give it a try after thanksgiving. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply by "offsetting" the date by the requisite number of days, e.g. 20th June until 1st January is `195` days therefore you can use this formula

```
=YEAR(P2+195)
```

**format result cell as number with zero decimal places**

Comment: What about leap years?

Comment: It's still 195 days from 20th June to 1st January (that's counting forwards) in any year, so the solution isn't affected by leap years - it will work for any date in any year, within Excel's date restrictions